# Wordpress tax query not working with 3 arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, fieldtype

I have following QUERY:

```
$query_args = array( 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array(17, 21, 18),
                'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
);
```

When I put 2 arguments in the array it is working but when I put 3 arguments in the array it is not working.
I can't find the answer anywhere, can someone help me please?

Comment: Then you probably do not have any products that are assigned to all three categories?

Comment: If you switch the operator to "OR" and you get an output, it's probable that the issue is what 04FS suggests.